# Tips on entering China as a British tourist

Tags: china, uk-citizens

I am British passport holder living in Australia. I plan to visit China next month. I was invited to a wedding and would like to explore the country.

Are there any special requirements currently in place to enter the country?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Are there any special requirements currently in place to enter the country?

Yes, you currently can't enter China mainland as a British tourist. Unlikely to change till 2023. See https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php for details and exceptions.

Comment: Metaculus currently predicts June 2024 for when China would open borders: https://www.metaculus.com/questions/9038/quarantine-free-us-travel-to-china/. So unfortunate we might still be 2 years away from that.

Comment: Yes, tourist visa (L) applications are currently not accepted. For completeness sake, it might be pointed out that applications for family reunion visa (Q and S), work visa (Z) and business visa (M) [are since quite recently accepted](https://www.chinahighlights.com/travelguide/china-travel-reopen-restrictions.htm) with similar requirements as before Covid. If eligible for one of those, it might be possible to combine that with attending a wedding. Of course, there is still 7 + 3 days of quarantine to deal with.

Comment: Some consulates (but maybe not all?) are now processing F visas ("noncommercial visit"). There's some vague chance that this could work out, but I wouldn't be especially optimistic about it.